# Extending AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I need to store an additional value (tag) within AlertDialog so I did extend this class. When using this new class it I do get an ClassCastException. What's wrong with my code?

Here's my extended AlertDialog:

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog {

    private long tag;

    public MyAlertDialog(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyAlertDialog(final Context context, final int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }

    public MyAlertDialog(final Context context, final boolean cancelable, final OnCancelListener cancelListener) {
        super(context, cancelable, cancelListener);
    }

    public long getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(final long tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

And this is part of an ListActivity using the new class:

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    private MyAlertDialog alertDialog;
    private long          id;

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        // ..
        processAlertDialog(id);
        // ..
        return super.onContextItemSelected(menuItem);
    }

    private void processAlertDialog(final long id) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(R.string.txt_reallydelete);
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        } );
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialogInterface, final int which) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();

                // do Something
            }
        } );

        // ClassCastException
        alertDialog = (MyAlertDialog) alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.setTag(id);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:

```
Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.AlertDialog
at com.test.app.MyListActivity.processAlertDialog(MyListActivity.java:234)
at com.test.app.MyListActivity.onContextItemSelected(MyListActivity.java:99)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2174)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2731)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:139)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:129)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:884)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3285)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1640)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: LogCat added. Line 234 is marked in the shown source. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you create your "MyAlertDialog", you didn't create actual "MyAlertDialog" object.
You created "AlertDialog.Builder" object and cast it to "MyAlertDialog".

Why are you doing like that??

I think you can create and show your own dialog like this,

```
private void processAlertDialog(final long id) {
   MyAlertDialog alertdialog = new MyAlertDialog(this);

   alertdialog.setCancelable(false);
   alertdialog.setMessage(R.string.txt_reallydelete);

   // your button's call back

   alertdialog.setTag(id);
   alertdialog.show();
}
```

Comment: alertDialogBuilder.create() does return an AlertDialog object. I do cast this to MyAlertDialog. This line gives the ClassCastException. What's wrong with this line?

Comment: Because you try to cast parent object to child object. if you cast "MyAlertDialog" to "AlertDialog" object, that gonna be fine. cuz "MyAlertDialog" extended "AlertDialog". However viceversa, it's not allow to JAVA. you can find this any JAVA books.

Comment: Arg. After all those apps - I still don't understand Java. It's always the same I struggle about: Why can I cast something bigger (child) to something smaller (parent). I always expect the other way round. However, I did upvote your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @HaraldWilhelm It's like 'All mangoes are fruit but all fruits are not mangoes'.

Answer (score 1):

To make things simple, you should create a class which extends `AlertDialog.Builder`.

```
public class MyAlertDialog extends AlertDialog.Builder {

    //add constructor stuff

    private long tag;
    public long getTag() {
        return tag;
    }

    public void setTag(final long tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }
}
```

and use it in your Activity by calling `show()` method.

```
yourBuilder.show();
```

*you dont need to call **create()** on builder since you are showing it directly*

Comment: Thanks. At first this looked promissing but there's one problem left. If my tag vars is in MyAlertDialogBuilder and I issue show() - without storing the AlertDialog that will be returned - how can I dismiss that dialog lateron? Whatever I do I end up with a CAST that's required for me but not possible. Let me explain a bit. I want to make those AlertDialogs survive orientation changes. So I store (on a ListActivity for example) the id in the AlertDialog and during onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() I put this id in the retained object and dismiss that dialog.

Comment: no, you dont need any casting when using this model. are you having different layouts for portrait and landscape? because if you dont, then your dialog can even survive orientation change without any further trick :)

Comment: Thanks again. I just did it that way (calling alertDialogBuilder.show() - no AlertDialog creation). There's no custom layout - just the Ok/Cancel buttons. After rotating the screen the dialog disappears and I do get an leaking-window-error. I doubt that an AlertDialog reappears after orientation change without my interaction. This is my experience in the last years. Do you by any chance use the Manifest setting android:configChanges? I don't use this setting and I do have to recreate all my dialogs myself.

Comment: Yes, you do need to set `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity to handle orientation change (if required) manually. Doing so will not prompt to any window leak warnings.

Comment: I don't get that. I never use android:configChanges="orientation". My AlertDialogs don't repaint itself after orientation change automatically. What's your magic trick?

Comment: just add this (`android:configChanges="orientation"`) to your activity in manifest and see the magic :)

Comment: @waqaslam, and what about dismissing it with code, we cannot `dismiss()` builder. Well, I mean not dismissing by Positive or Negative button. In my case I'm trying to dismiss it after 30 seconds.